# Input mask literal character not found in DLookup?

Tags: database, ms-access, authentication, vba, input-mask

I have 2 textboxes in a form and 2 fields in a table `tbStudentLogs`. What I want to do is validate that `txtLoginID.Value` exists in the field `StudentID`. If so, I want to validate that `txtPassword.text` exists in the same record for which `txtLoginID.text` is the StudentID. Here is the [code](http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=71114) I used but I adapted the names:

```
Private Sub Command15_Click()
 If IsNull(Me.txtLoginID) Then
     MsgBox "Please enter LoginID", vdInformation, "LoginID Required"
     Me.txtLoginID.SetFocus
 Else
     'process the job
     If (IsNull(DLookup("StudentID", "tbStudentLogs", "StudentID ='" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'"))) Or _
       (IsNull(DLookup("SPassword", "tbStudentLogs", "SPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
        'MsgBox "Incorrect LoginID or Password"
     Else
        'MsgBox "Login and Password Correct"
        'Code to open new form etc,.
     End If

 End If
End Sub
```

But this did not work. The exact problem I get is: The program identifies null field, but then I can never login. In other words, I can't get to the last `Else` part. As in the password and ID are always wrong. I checked spelling and the like, but the problem is definitely in my code. Is it the `IsNull` part?

---

**EDIT:**

I realised the problem is not with my code. For my StudentID, the input mask is:

```
>\S00009
```

For example, a user has `S0001` and password `1234`. If I enter the username as `0001`, that is, without the S, it works. Otherwise, it does not work. Why?

---

As for Erik's answer, this is what I got:
[image]

Note now that without the "S" it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that you're using string delimiters for a field that likely contains a number, thus always returning `Null`.

Change `DLookup("StudentID", "tbStudentLogs", "StudentID ='" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'")` to `DLookup("StudentID", "tbStudentLogs", "StudentID =" & Me.txtLoginID.Value)`

Note that this type of login doesn't offer true security, and storing passwords in plain text is a bad practice. Also, your code is open to SQL injection. Anyone entering `' OR 1=1 Or 'A' = '` as his password will get past the password check.

Comment: That gave off a "runtime error `whatever the StudentID was`"

Comment: I added a screenshot